# Google Calendar API PHP (400) Missing end time

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I use the following code to create an event but got error.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar();
$calendarId = "<some calendar id>";
$startDate = "2017-12-04";
$startTime = "18:00:00";
$endDate = "2017-12-04";
$endTime = "19:00:00";
$tzOffset = "+08";
$newEvent = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$newEvent->setSummary("title");
$newEvent->setLocation("where");
$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime("{$startDate}T{$startTime}.000{$tzOffset}:00");
$newEvent->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime("{$endDate}T{$endTime}.000{$tzOffset}:00");
$newEvent->setEnd($end);
$newEvent->setDescription("desc");

$result = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $newEvent);
```

The result as follows.

```
Error calling PUT <some url>: (400) Missing end time.
```

So what's wrong? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the reason. It was my bad.

The function was to create the whole schedule on Google Calendar based on the schedule in my system. I tried to truncate the summary field before this function. The problem was here since there're chances that the summary field is multibyte string while I used substr() to truncate, the resulting string would occasionally contain unwanted characters. Those characters malformed the JSON created by the API. And the server probably parse the JSON properly therefore couldn't get some attributes, say, the end time attribute. The error message was correct but misleading.